# Javascript: Using an OR conditional in an object when property may not exist

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm trying to find an elegant Javascript way to do the following:

```
var c;
if(obj[i].cost){
  c = obj[i].cost.toFixed(2);
}else{
  c = null
}

arr.push(c);
```

In practice I have 5 - 10 of these elements and I'm trying to find a more efficient way of coding this. Something like this:

```
arr.push(obj[i].cost.toFixed(2) || null)
```

would be lovely, but breaks when there is no `cost` property.

Is there a minimal-code way to do this without doing a verbose `if/else` statement for each property?

Comment: The ternary operator is shorter than an if/else.

Comment: What's wrong with a ternary statement? `arr.push((obj[i].cost) ? obj[i].cost.toFixed(2) : null)`

Comment: If you really want to shorten it use a ternary operator, otherwise the if/else is the cleanest way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using the `Conditional (ternary) Operator`, something like this:

```
arr.push(obj[i].cost ? obj[i].cost.toFixed(2) : null)
```

For more information about the `Conditional (ternary) Operator`, please take a look at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: Ah, excellent. Didn't think of using a ternary operator here, but this is very clean.

Comment: this is legit, I think Im gonna be using the ternary this way a lot more!

Comment: This is certainly not 'clean' in the usual sense (easy to read), but its just cool,

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
var nullCost = {
    toFixed: function() { return null; }
};

var c = (obj[i].cost || nullCost).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your code uses `i` in an indexer, it seems likely that it's being used in the body of a loop.

```
var c;
if(obj[i].cost){
//    ^^^
  c = obj[i].cost.toFixed(2);
//       ^^^
}else{
  c = null
}
arr.push(c);
```

I'm going to make a huge assumption, so please correct it because there's a good chance that it's wrong. I'm going to assume that the usage will look something along the lines of:

```
var arr = [];
for (i in obj) {
  var c;
  if (obj[i].cost) {
    c = obj[i].cost.toFixed(2);
  } else {
    c = null;
  }
  arr.push(c);
}
```

***assuming this structure is reasonably accurate***, then the code can be simplified into something more functional.

Instead of iterating over the keys of the object, you can access the keys as a collection, and then use array methods to apply functions to the entire collection:

```
var arr,
    obj;

//this is a utility. It would be nice to have Object.values,
//but it's not supported in enough browsers yet
function values(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
    return obj[key];
  });
}

//this function gets a cost from a particular value
//it's reusable and concise
function getCost(value) {
  return value.cost
    ? value.cost.toFixed(2)
    : null;
}

//get the data however you get it
obj = ...;

//this is where everything actually happens
arr = values(obj).map(getCost);
```

This is longer than what you wrote originally. That isn't necessarily a bad thing.

There is a tendency among programmers to go for the shortest possible code. I would encourage you to strive for the most readable code. If it's readable it's easy to understand, and if it's easy to understand, it's easy to debug.

For example: The code you provided translates `0` values into `null`. It's possible that this is a bug, and what you should have written was:

```
if (obj[i].cost != null) {
```

If you reuse this snippet over and over in your code, you'll need to fix the same snippet in multiple locations.

If instead you've abstracted this small piece of logic into a simple function. You will only need to correct that bug once, and the rest of your code will use the fixed version.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
arr.push((cost = obj[i].cost) && cost.toFixed(2) || null)
```

Since you're trying to write elegant JS, I suggest you look into CoffeeScript:

```
arr.push obj[i].cost?.toFixed(2)
```

see the [compiled js](http://js2.coffee/#coffee/try:arr.push%20obj%5Bi%5D.cost%3F.toFixed(2)). You technically get undefined rather than null if it does not exist, but CoffeeScript generally lets you write considerably elegant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var c; //initiate variable
c = obj[i].cost ? obj[i].cost.toFixed(2) : null; //ternary for if/else block
arr.push(c); //push value to array
```

Comment: You need to add sufficient explanation along with code as per rules.

Comment: just updated with some comments. sorry im a newbie to stacoverflow